# react redux put formatting logic in selector vs in mapstatetoprops

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm fetching a list of items from the server and storing it in a reducer. The reducer has a `getItemsList` selector. Each item is returned from the server in a raw form, and I have written a formatter function that I need to apply to it. The question is, would it be best to apply it inside the `getItemsList` selector, or, make the selector return raw data and apply the formatter inside `mapStateToProps`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that one of the jobs of a selector is to separate the shape of stored data from the code that uses it. To this end your formatter code belongs in a selector, possibly named for the formatting it applies to the data.

An exception to this would be if your formatter was a form of normalisation function such as provided by normailzr which are applied to the data before it is added to the store.

`mapStateToProps` should call whichever selector functions give it the data required by the component.